# Why does hashcode() returns an integer and not long?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, hashcode, bucket

In java, hashcode() method, returns integer instead of long. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: What would be the advantage in producing a long? Your hash table is not going to contain over 2 billion buckets.

Comment: @khelwood Something like this I wrote maybe 10 years ago.... and guess what: I was told that the company has hundreds of billions items in their table (obviously not JDK HashMap).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, one good reason is that the `hashCode` based data structures (`HashSet`, `HashMap`) use an array to store the bins, and arrays are limited to `int` indices. You will gain nothing by a `long` `hashCode()` if you must map it to an `int` array index.

Comment: Yes, but since many years, this is insufficient for some users, who need a custom huge Map (obviously using multiple arrays or off-heap). Java is simply old, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

Using the hashCode is to have N buckets where the hashCode % N determines the bucket of elements, hopefully being 1 (no conflicting hashCodes).

For N, for the hash code, an int is entirely sufficient; indeed one needs to have most variety in the lower bits; having a long without using the higher bits (when N would be a power of 2), would be counter productive.

Speed of course is a requirement too: int being slightly better on the final CPU.