# why hashcode based data structure use array to create bins?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, hashset

I was reading an answer to a question asked here:
[Why does hashcode() returns an integer and not long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49489116/why-does-hashcode-returns-an-integer-and-not-long)

My question is: Why hashcode based data structures use an array to create bins?

Comment: Since the prime use of hashCode() is to determine which slot to insert an object into, arrays prove to be the easiest "low-level" data structure having constant random access.

Comment: Indexed access of an array element is a small constant cost: **O(1)**, Hence `array[hashcode % array,length]` is ideal. A tree would need **O(log n)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because array is a low-level data structure which allows random access to its elements.

You need a "low-level" data structure to base a "higher-level" data structure on.

You need random access so that you can address bins very fast.

Answer (score 0):

cause, an array is based on **integer-based** indexes! now you can show some curiosity, why array using integer-based indexing. one of the assumptions should be -- if you could able to use other types (real numbers) rather than using integer, just think how many dimension you would capable to add -- 
for example --

```
for 1-th index, you could capable to add sub-indexes like -- 1.1, 1.2, 1.1.2, 1.1.1.1.2 and so on so forth!
```

doing so, it will create more overhead, rather than  popping up the solution we want.